# The association \Entity\Specialists#images refers to the owning side field Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media#spec which does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

```
class Media extends BaseMedia

    /**
 * @var Specialists
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Specialists", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="spec", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $spec;

class Specialists

   /**
 * @var Media
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", mappedBy="spec")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="images", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $images;
```

after php app / console doctrine: schema: validate an error

> [Mapping] FAIL - The entity-class 'Specialists \ SpecialistsBundle \ Entity \ Specialists' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association Specialists \ SpecialistsBundle \ Entity \ Specialists # images refers to the owning side field Application \ Sonata \ MediaBundle \ Entity \ Media # spec which does not exist.

I would appreciate an answer

Comment: Have you proved to clear cache? `php app / console cache:clear`

Comment: yes I do php app / console cache:clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media bundle originally uses the XML format maybe you must define your media entity mapping informations by modifying xml config file

try this,

```
class Media extends BaseMedia
{
    /*
    * ....
    */
    private $spec;

    //others attributes, getters and setters there
   // ...
}
```

then alter xml configuration file initially located at:  "src/Application/Sonata/MediaBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Media.orm.xml"
It's something looking like

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity
        name="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media"
        table="media__media"
        >

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>   
        <!-- then you add this -->
         <many-to-one field="spec" target-entity="\path-to\Specialists" inversed-by="images">
            <join-column name="spec" referenced-column-name="id" />
        </many-to-one>
        <!-- end -->
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Then try to update your doctrine schema